# Adding shebang with mac

Tags: python, sed, shebang

I want to add a shebang at the beginning of my file.py script using sed in Mac.

My file.py starts like this:

```
import os
import sys
import shutil
```

I have tried:

```
sed -i '.bak' '1 s|^.*$|#!/usr/bin/env python2|g' file.py
```

But then my file looks like this (the first line has been substituted by the shebang):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import sys
import shutil
```

How can I use sed to get this?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import os
import sys
import shutil
```

Comment: Or you could use `cat`

Comment: Use the `i` command to insert a line, the `s` command replaces the line.

Comment: Why use python v2?

Comment: It is required by the script (only the first lines are shown above)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to prefix the line with the line you want to add.

```
sed '1s|.*|#!/usr/bin/env python2\n&|'
```